# How to get POSIXct to return a non-null value when converting a character string (with milliseconds) in R?

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I am trying to convert the date-time character string "29.04.2023 06:08:01.165" using the POSIXct function, however I only get null values when I try to convert the whole thing:

```
test <- "29.04.2023 06:08:01.165"
z <- as.POSIXct(test,format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%OS")
z
[1] NA
```

What am I doing wrong? It works fine when I just try to return it to the second, but I need the milliseconds.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't see dashes in your `test` string - you have dots `.` as separators and the `format=` needs to match exactly. I can't see how it would have worked with just the seconds either.

Answer (score 0):

This should correctly convert the date string to a POSIXct object.

z <- as.POSIXct(test, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%OS")

```
test <- "29.04.2023 06:08:01.165"
    z <- as.POSIXct(test, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%OS")
```

this is the result:

```
z
[1] "2023-04-29 06:08:01.164 CEST"
```

Comment: And if you set `options(digits.secs=3)` you also see the milliseconds on output.